# Django1.3 collectstatic command makes the filename lowercase

Tags: django

I'm using the Django1.3 and python2.7.1.
The collectstatic is a new feature in Django1.3,so i try to use it in my project.
After setup the STATICFILES_DIRS and STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL to include each app static directory,

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'static/')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'     
STATICFILES_DIRS = (  
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".  
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.  
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.  
    os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'common/static/'),     
    os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'apps/brokee/static/'),  
    os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'apps/home/static/')       
)
```

i run the command:
**python manage.py collectstatic**
The static files are copied to the /static/ folder,but I found that all javascript file's name  become lowercase.I try it several times and the same result got.
I wonder if it is a bug or something I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

See this ticket https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15636

Comment: Thanks，but the ticket doesn't say how to fix it.